# How do I setup TeamCity for public access over https?

Tags: tomcat, teamcity, reverse-proxy

How do I setup TeamCity 4.0 so that I can access it over port 443 on the internet?  e.g. https://teamcity.mydomain.com

I am running IIS 7 on the same server that TeamCity is installed.  I see two options:

1. Setup TeamCity to use port 8443 and
   create a reverse proxy in IIS that
   routes requests to the TeamCity
   public IP address to the Tomcat port
   on the internal IP address.
2. Setup Tomcat to run on a different
   IP address than IIS 7, and configure
   TeamCity to run on port 443.

I'm not sure on the details of either of these steps.

Comment: The accepted answer is for Apache. Did you use the instructions on the referenced page for IIS?

Comment: Mark, IIS 7 ARR should work just fine.  I just haven't tried it.  We already had an Apache reverse proxy so that's what we used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It requires configuring the bundled Tomcat server for https.  See here:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server

and here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

I also setup Tomcat to listen on just one IP Address.  All of this turned out to be a real pain, and I still am not able to run TeamCity as a service.  I can only run it at the command line.  If I were going to do this over, I would install TeamCity to run on the default port, and reverse proxy to it using [IIS7 Application Request Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/489/using-the-application-request-routing-module/) or Apache Virtual Directories.

[Edit]
I have done this over, and I used IIS Application Request Routing to set up a reverse proxy. It works perfectly, and Team City upgrades are painless as well.

Comment: I went directly to the IIS ARR because of your comment and got it up and running in like 5 minutes. I've got a feeling you saved me many frustrating hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not expecting high server load you can avoid using IIS or Apache and enable SSL right in the Tomcat. This is simpler to configure. The only drawback is high CPU usage when client connects to the server (during negotiation stage), after that CPU usage is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also use load these 2 modules

```
LoadModule proxy_module bin/mod_proxy.so 
LoadModule proxy_http_module bin/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyPass /TeamCity http://localhost/TeamCity
ProxyPassReverse /TeamCity http://localhost/TeamCity
```